# FreeRTOS.h file not found - VS Code for Mac despite includePath modified & all filed in project folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, include-path, freertos

I am trying my best to include FreeRTOS into a new Project on VS Code for Mac.

I have created a directory for my project, added a main.cpp,  configure the default build task for C/C++ clang. I have also created the c_cpp_properties.json.

My project consists of three folders; 'src' containing my main.cpp, and 'FreeRTOS' containing all of the source files for FreeRTOS (include & portable folders), and 'Demo' containing a demo app built for the CORTEX_ATSAM3X_Atmel_Studio board (that comes with the FreeRTOS download).

In my main.cpp file, I have an empty main function, that I can build successfully.  The minute I try to add #include <FreeRTOS.h> to main.cpp, I am given the error FreeRTOS.h file not found.

What is interesting, is the first time I try to build, it recognises FreeRTOS.h, and the error I see is that it cannot find a file included in the FreeRTOS.h. To remedy this, I add the specific subdirectory to c_cpp_properties. I rebuild and then it shows me another file it cannot locate. So I work again manually amending another subdirectory. After 5 or 6 times, suddenly it fails to find FreeRTOS.h.  When I delete all of the includePath entries except "${workspaceFolder}/**" I cannot get back to my starting point.

I have spent the last two days stuck on this, reading forums, starting my process again and I still cannot see where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I run into the same issue.
The problem was **FreeRTOSConfig.h** contains this definition
`#define CMSIS_device_header "stm32h7xx.h"`
which is next used in **freertos_os2.h** header (only):
`#include CMSIS_device_header`
and that is where build gets confused. It is not the perfect solution but removing the **CMSIS_device_header** variable and specifying **stm32h7xx.h** header directly in **freertos_os2.h** file solved my problem.